# Mockito Spy a specific method that is several method-calls deep

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have the following line of code in Java:

```
boolean x = app1().app2().app3().returnBoolean();
```

Let's say `app3` has several methods, but I would like to only mock the behavior of `returnBoolean` inside app3 to always return true using Mockito. The other methods of `app3`, `app1` and `app2` remain the same. Somehow I need to do a `RETURN_DEEP_STUBS` by spying `app3`. I did some research, and I think Mockito only supports `RETURN_DEEP_STUBS` with mock.

I am able to simulate the behavior with the code below:

```
App1 app1Spy = spy(app1());
App2 app2Spy = spy(app1Spy.app2());
App3 app3Spy = spy(app2Spy.app3());
doReturn(app2Spy).when(app1Spy).app2();
doReturn(app3Spy).when(app2Spy).app3();
doReturn(true).when(app3Spy).returnBoolean();
```

But the code is rather lengthy. Is there another way of achieving this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of Answers.RETURNS\_DEEP\_STUBS for a spy in mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822542/equivalent-of-answers-returns-deep-stubs-for-a-spy-in-mockito)

Comment: Well, the example I gave is essentially what the post you gave is doing. Wondering if there is a better way of doing it.